# Set Focus on a Sub Widget TextBox in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, focus

How can I set the default focus to be on a TextBox which is a sub widget in my current view?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=SomeWidget.UnderTextBoxName}">
   <MyWidget x:Name="SomeWidget" Text="A" />
   <TextBox x:Name="TxtB" Text="B" />
</StackPanel>
```

...thought that might work, but no luck?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FocusedElement="{x:Reference Name=UnderTextBoxName}"`. No need for Binding.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <MyWidget x:Name="SomeWidget" Text="A" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{x:Reference Name=UnderTextBoxName}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtB" Text="B" />
</StackPanel>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to focus on TxtB, I guess it's confusing that I included it in there. My MyWidget has several widgets inside, one of which is a TextBox with x:name=UnderTextBoxName -- how can I make the focus start on that one?

Comment: It was just example if you want to so then just set `FocusedElement="{x:Reference Name=UnderTextBoxName}"` I have updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work if I have multiple MyWidgets though, and consequently multiple TextBoxs below with x:name=UnderTextBoxName? Is it possible to do something like a reference to SomeWidget.UnderTextBoxName?

Comment: Ok if it is so then apply `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{x:Reference Name=UnderTextBoxName}"` to only one of the MyWidgets  of whom UnderTextBoxName you want to set focus(dont apply it to other Widgets). I have updated the answer.